# MS Access linked picture slow display

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I have a database with about 10,000 records. Each of these records has an image stored on a shared drive and a file path associated with the record. When the user runs a report the images are displayed by setting the image control's `Control Source` property to `DLookUp("[tblMasterList].[imagePath]","[tblMasterList]","[txtID]=[tblMasterList].[ID]")` The problem is that when scrolling through the report there is a lag when each of the image controls come in to view to the time the image is displayed. Orginally I thought this was due to the image being pulled over the network, however, I copied all of the images to my harddrive and updated the image paths and I still had the same problem. Is there a better way to display images without storing them in the database?

Answer (score 0):

- COMPACT AND REPAIR your Access database. If you get close to the 2G limit that may slow things down. I don't think that's the problem with only 10,000 records, but sometimes if the database is used quite a bit then excess memory may still be allocated.
- Are the file paths using absolute paths versus relative paths? Since you tested them on your local hard drive I doubt thats the problem.
- Is the ID in tableMasterList and txtID Primary Key'd? The delay may be on the search.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas @actkatiemacias, I tried all of those and unfortunately I'm still having the problem with lag. We were previously having problems with the 2G limit, that's why I pulled the pictures out of the database. Is there anyway to pre-load the pictures so that I don't have the lag problem?